# AES encrypting large files in iOS

Tags: ios, aes, large-data

I am creating a chat application wherein I have to encrypt a large video and decrypt it as required. I am using the following code, but it crashes on large files because of memory constraints. Is there any other way to encrypt large files so that it does not crash.

```
+ (NSData *)addPaddingToData:(NSData *)data
                  paddingKey:(NSString *)keyString
                   paddingiv:(NSString *)ivString {
    NSArray * chunkedArray = [NSData chunkedArrayForData:data chunkSize:10240];

    NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    for (NSData *d in chunkedArray) {
        NSData * encryptedData = [[StringEncryption alloc] encrypt:d key:keyString iv:ivString];
        [mutableData appendData:encryptedData];
    }

    return (NSData *)mutableData;
}

+ (NSData *)removePaddingToData:(NSData *)data
                     paddingKey:(NSString *)keyString
                      paddingiv:(NSString *)ivString {
    NSArray * chunkedArray = [NSData chunkedArrayForData:data chunkSize:10256];
    NSMutableData *mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    for (NSData *d in chunkedArray) {
        NSData *decryptedData = [[StringEncryption alloc] decrypt:d  key:keyString iv:ivString];
        [mutableData appendData:decryptedData];
    }

    return (NSData *)mutableData;
}

+ (NSArray *)chunkedArrayForData:(NSData *)data chunkSize:(NSUInteger)size {
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    NSUInteger chunkSize = size;
    NSUInteger offset = 0;
    NSMutableArray * chunkedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    do {
        NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
        NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[data bytes] + offset
                                             length:thisChunkSize
                                       freeWhenDone:NO];
        offset += thisChunkSize;
        [chunkedArray addObject:chunk];
    } while (offset < length);

    return chunkedArray;
}
```

Comment: What is the class `StringEncryption? It is a little disconcerting since data, not strings are being encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

Use streams which only read in a small bit of a file at a time.

The current code reads in the entire file to be encrypted initially, encrytes the entire file chunk by chunk into a `mutableData` instance. In the end you have the contents of both the unencrypted and encrypted data in memory at once. Using the chunks does not reduce the memory footprint.

There is another problem with this "chunked" method, the `StringEncryption` class most likely does not just extend the encryption but restarts with the same iv for each chunk. This is not produce the same encrypted output as a single encryption.

To use streams create an `NSStream` instance for the input and output. Use Common Crypto but not in the Stateless, one-shot but rather using `CCCryptorCreate`, `CCCryptorUpdate` and `CCCryptorFinal`.

- Create input/output streams (`NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream`)
- First create a context with `CCCryptorCreate`.
- Loop reading some data from the steam, call `CCCryptorUpdate` with that data and write the result to the stream.
- If padding is used call `CCCryptorFinal` and write the final data to the stream.
- Close the streams.

This way only a small portion of the file is in memory at any one time.

As usual you should look at [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) to see if that solution fits your needs.