# iOS how to decrypt an encrypted large file?

Tags: ios, file, security, encryption, aes

This may not be an iOS question - logic from other platforms could probably apply here too.

On iPhone, I am successfully able to encrypt and decrypt data such as `String`, `UIImage` etc. using `CryptoKit` as following:

```
import CryptoKit

do {
    
    let alicePrivateKey = P521.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
    let bobPrivateKey = P521.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
    let alicePublicKey = alicePrivateKey.publicKey
    let bobPublicKey = bobPrivateKey.publicKey
    
    let shared_secret_alice = try alicePrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: bobPublicKey)
    let shared_secret_bob = try bobPrivateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: alicePublicKey)
    
    guard shared_secret_alice == shared_secret_bob else {
        throw "Shared secret isn't the same between Alice and Bob"
    }
    
    guard let dataToSend = UIImage(named: "image")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else {
        return
    }
    
    print("original decrypted: \(dataToSend.hex())")
    
    let alice_key = shared_secret_alice.x963DerivedSymmetricKey(using: SHA512.self , sharedInfo: Data(), outputByteCount: 16)
    let encrypted = try encryptedData(decryptedData: dataToSend, key: alice_key)
    
    print("encrypted: \(encrypted.hex())")
    
    let bobs_key = shared_secret_bob.x963DerivedSymmetricKey(using: SHA512.self , sharedInfo: Data(), outputByteCount: 16)
    
    let decryptedAgain = try decryptData(encryptedData: encrypted, key: bobs_key)
            
    print("decrypted again: \(decryptedAgain.hex())")
    
    print("decrypted is same as original decrypted?: \(dataToSend.hex() == decryptedAgain.hex())")
    
    guard let decryptedImage = UIImage(data: decryptedAgain) else {
        return
    }
    
    print("decryptedImage: \(decryptedImage)")
    
} catch {
    print("Error encrypting: \(error)")
}

func encryptedData(decryptedData : Data, key : SymmetricKey) throws -> Data {
    let sealedMessage = try AES.GCM.seal(decryptedData, using: key)
    
    guard let encryptedData = sealedMessage.combined else {
        throw "Error in sealedMessage"
    }
    
    return encryptedData
}

func decryptData(encryptedData : Data, key : SymmetricKey) throws -> Data {
    
    let sealedBoxRecreated = try AES.GCM.SealedBox(combined: encryptedData)
    
    return try AES.GCM.open(sealedBoxRecreated, using: key);
}

extension String: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { return self }
}

extension Data {
    func hex() -> String {
        return String(map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined().prefix(20)) + "..."
    }
}
```

My problem is that the above works okay for small images or strings but for images/videos/files of larger size, it requires me to load the entire data in memory to encrypt and decrypt. This would quickly run out of memory for larger files. So I am looking for a better solution which doesn't require loading the entire thing in memory.

I did find the following questions:

[IOS - How do I AES decrypt a large file if the file is too large to load all of it into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724851/ios-how-do-i-aes-decrypt-a-large-file-if-the-file-is-too-large-to-load-all-of)

[AES encrypting large files in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397707/aes-encrypting-large-files-in-ios)

But these are from 2012 which is long before modern `CryptoKit` became available.

1. Is there some newer way this came be done effectively?
2. I understand the concept of breaking the data into smaller chunks, reading the smaller chunks, encrypting them, appending them to a new location. However, I am not sure how to decrypt it afterwards? What I am confused about is - in the final file which is the appended encrypted chunks, how should I determine each individual encrypted chunk to decrypt?

For example:

Lets say original file is `123456`

I break this down into 6 chunks: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`

I encrypt each of these chunks: `hf1d`, `cd2`, `12dm`, `7d3`, `55gr`, `61w3d`

I append them all to create the combined file: `hf1dcd212dm7d355gr61w3d`

Now I need to decrypt this combined file.

2. How should I break it down into each chunk for decryption? As far as I am aware, the encrypted chunks can vary in length.

Or am I very wrong in my logic?

Comment: Chunking is one option yes. Why would the chunks differ in size? They can all be the same size, possibly except the last one (and since you know the size of the file, it would be easy to calculate the size of the last chunk). Do note that normally you'd try authenticated encryption, in that case the order and number of chunks also need to be authenticated.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in my code example, the size of `dataToSend.count` is slightly smaller from `encrypted.count`. Any reason why? Can the resulting size be determined beforehand? And how should I go about authenticating the order and number of chunks?

Comment: Also see [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679889) that suggests using `Data(contentsOf:options)` with a mapped option to access the file in-place mapped into memory. There are still file size limitations on IOS due to address space limits, but it should be good for a few GB I would think

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation From the documentation "A combined element composed of the nonce, encrypted data, and authentication tag.". That's 12 + X + 16 so probably the sealed data is 28 bytes bigger. And yes, if you can use memory mapped IO, but remember that GCM has an upper limit slightly lower than 64 GiB. Sounds like al lot but yeah, not all files will fit in that.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly 28 bytes bigger. How should I go about authenticating the order and number of chunks?

Comment: HMAC the authentication tags, for instance. Don't forget that you need to check all of them before using the data.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sorry if it's a stupid question but I don't see "authentication tags" anywhere in my code so far. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm/sealedbox/tag) which talks about the `authentication tag`. What should be set as the `authentication tag`? Can I use Bob's public key for that? In [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916728/getting-authentcationfailure-with-nonce-and-tag-using-cryptokit), they say to "not provide a pre determined tag while encrypting".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Couldn't I use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143413/sha-256-of-large-file-using-cryptokit) to calculate the SHA256 of the entire file and append it at the beginning of the overall encrypted file? Then validate the hash when decrypting?

Comment: The authentication tags of GCM are part of the sealed box thingy. Hashes do not provide that kind of security, you need a MAC such as HMAC which is a specialized keyed hash. Anybody can calculate a hash after all.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I understand. However, I still don't understand what I should be setting the `authentication tag` to in order to ensure the order and number of chunks? Also, the `authentication tag` would be on each individual chunk. So how would that ensure order and number of chunks? I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is this practice documented somewhere?

Comment: Heh, a MAC is used to calculate an authentication tag. What you can do is to verify the concatenation of the authentication tags calculated with GCM by one that is calculated by HMAC. So each chunk would have a tag *and* the HMAC would be used to validate the authentication tags. As the order, amount and value of the tags represent the various chunks the HMAC can be used to validate the combination.